# Matching very close numbers within a tolerance - Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a set of ID's and numbers - For example,

```
ABC - 123.45
ABC - 123.45
ABC - 123.44
CDE - 123.45
ABC - 123.33
```

Now, if I wanted to match things that were exactly the same, that's really easy - Create a unique ID with the letters and numbers, and do a match/vlookup on it to find ones that are the same to pair them with each other. My question is, how can I do a "fuzzy pairing" within a given tolerance?

One idea I have is this - for a .10 tolerance, I can have my unique ID be =A1&Round(B1,1), then do an exact match with that. Are there any other ways to do matching with some tolerance built in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, thought you don't say, you want to do this in a formula and you want to be able to use `VLOOKUP` with the result. You normally want to handle positive and negative differences within your tolerance, so you really need to find the absolute difference. I would add a column with a new formula based on the search value:

```
=A1&(ABS(FindNum-B1) < 0.10)
```

Then `VLOOKUP` for `FindID&TRUE`.